# "Fotorama" jquery plugin size glitch

Tags: javascript, jquery, fotorama

Here's the screencast: http://screencast.com/t/NK7l2VfT

And the code:

```
            <div class="fotorama"
                data-allowfullscreen="native"
                data-nav="thumbs"
                data-hash="true"
                data-loop="true"
                data-keyboard="true"

                data-width="100%"
                data-ratio="800/600"
                >
              <?php

                for ( $i=1; $i<12; $i++ ) {
                    echo '
                        <a href="http://s.fotorama.io/okonechnikov/'.$i.'.jpg">
                            <img src="http://s.fotorama.io/okonechnikov/'.$i.'-thumb.jpg">
                        </a>';

                }
              ?>
            </div>
```

Seems like if thumbnail loads faster than main image, the #fotorama div sometimes takes it's size from thumbnail. Any ideas how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like adding

```
data-auto="false"
data-width="100%"
data-ratio="800/600"
```

And moving fotorama initialization to

```
$(document).ready(function() {});
```

fixes the problem.